# Multiple "Sub-Applications" In One (Conflicting CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I've been tasked to migrate an existing web application written in Ruby over to React and Node, however to make the migration seamless and quick (while we work on modularizing everything), we were hoping that the existing stylesheets could be ported over.

However, due to the way React bundles everything, there are a lot of conflicts in rules and styles. Short of hacks to enable / disable stylesheets is there any way to migrate over entire sheets and dynamically switch between them without having conflicts (I've tried namespacing them as well, however I haven't been able to achieve perfect results).

The application uses different versions of Bootstrap, one of my latest attempts to kind of "hackishly" solve the problem was something along the lines of:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('link')).forEach(e => {
    if (e.getAttribute('href') === "/assets/css/application.css") {
      e.disabled = false;
    } else if (e.getAttribute('href') === "/assets/css/parent_css.css") {
      e.disabled = true;
    } else if (e.getAttribute('href') === "/assets/css/sb-admin-2.css") {
      e.disabled = true;
    }
  });
```

Which works however there's a flicker as the style sheets are determined. Is there a way to prevent React from bundling the CSS and dynamically selecting a stylesheet? (Or perhaps even prevent React from bundling it all together?)